# using shell variable in awk and using for/while loop

Tags: shell, awk, variable

How can I loop through and achieve below with passing shell variable in `awk` using  `for`/`while` loop?

I have a text file like below.

```
mark     10 20 30
lawrence 40 22 60
mark     11 12 13
mike     15 16 17
lawrence 21 22 23
mike     31 32 33
mike     41 42 47
```

I want the output to be like below 
(2nd column denotes the count of occurrence of each name)

I had one more requirement sorry asking again
output would be like

if mark has value 20(in third column), its occurence should be printed in next colmn

if mike has value 32(in third column), its occurence should be printed in next column

if lawrence has value 22(in third column), its occurence should be printed in next column

mark     2  1

mike     3  1

lawrence 2 2

This is what it looks like. I want the text file to be passed as below.  Can you please help?

Command i am  using now

```
n=$(date +"%Y%m%d");

LogDataN=`tail -10 "$n".txt`   -- my text file which contains the above data

A=`echo "$LogDataN" | awk '{ c["$1"]++ } END { for (name in c) print name, c[name] }' `

echo "$A"
```

Comment: just `sort | uniq -c` really

Comment: @n.caillou That would take the full line into account and would therefore not work.

Comment: You must be joking about adding six specific data values (3 names, 3 scores) to the original requirement at this stage. What do you do when sarah shows up? Put n/a in the extra column, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite see why you would be wanting to pass any shell variables to `awk` here.

```
tail "$(date +'%Y%m%d.txt')" |
awk '{ c[$1]++ } END { for (name in c) print name, c[name] }'
```

`tail` extracts the last 10 lines of text from the given file by default, so `-n 10` (or the deprecated `-10`) is not needed.  The `date` command is used to create the filename to read from.

The `awk` code uses the first column as a key in the associative array `c`, which holds the number of times each name has been seen. The count for a name is incremented for each line read from the file.  At the end, the names and the associated counts are outputted.

Note that there is no use for shell variables here.

Comment: I get below while running
{ c[$4]++ } END { for (name in c) print name, c[name] }: command not found. please help. Should I pass sumthning in "name" ? Sorry to bother , new in this area

Comment: command  i am using   A=`echo "$LogDataN" | $awk '{ c[$1]++ } END { for (name in c) print name, c[name] }' `   where "$LogDataN" contains the data from text file.

Comment: @user411502 You say you have a text file. Run my command _exactly_ as I've shown (`awk`, not `$awk`, and don't use `echo`) with the name of your text file as the file argument at the end. If you need to clarify your question, please edit it.

Comment: This is what it looks like. I want the text file to be passed as below.  Can you please help?

n=$(date +"%Y%m%d");
LogDataN=`tail -10 "$n".txt`   -- my text file which contains the data
A=`echo "$LogDataN" | awk '{ c["$1"]++ } END { for (name in c) print "name", c[name] }' `
echo "$A"

Comment: @user411502 If you want to clarify you question, please edit it. I can't give an answer to something that was not actually specified in the question, that would disconnect my answer from the question.

Comment: edited. please help.

Comment: @user411502 See updated answer. Also note that you should not introduce more quotes in the `awk` code.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked.. I has just another requirement . I have edited the question. Can you please help and it would be of great help if we can incorporate in the same command

Comment: @Kushalnanda.. It was of great help... Can you please help me to get out of this as well please.